# Change number of lines mouse wheel scrolls in WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, scroll, listbox, mouse, mousewheel

In a WPF listbox, rotating mouse wheel will scroll list by the number of lines specified in Windows Control Panel, in Mouse Wheel options.

How can I change this, for example I want to scroll WPF ListBox, one line anytime, using mouse wheel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated it is a control panel setting and you are trying to override it. That will confuse the user. I recommend you to not do that.

However you could try and override various events and position the vertical scrolling by using `scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(...);`

Comment: Yep, but ScrollToVerticalOffset is not precise and it's slow.

Comment: My ListBox has huge items with images in them. Scrolling 3 lines at once may skip lines in small windows. I think it's legitimate to reduce the number to 2 or even 1 here, initially considering the current user preference.

Comment: PS: I just found a better solution for my scenario: Set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` for the `ListBox`. This lets the user scroll between items which is much nicer.

Comment: @LonelyPixel - that is a nice addition however it will still scroll by the number of lines set in the configuration but it will not scroll at a pixel level

Answer (score 0):

As stated by ygoe in a comment, what you are looking for is :

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

In my tests, it does scroll the list one line at a time.

Of course, you should consider that it overrides a global windows setting, as stated by Erno